# A column in a table is referred to by multiple physical column names

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mysql-workbench

I have a spring boot project using JPA, So I am trying to map two tables into a third one using their Id :
for example I have a coupon class, I have a customer class I want to take customer id and coupon id into a third table.

I have coupons:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "coupons")
public class Coupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private long coup_id;
    private String title;
    private String start;
    private String end; 
    private int amount; 
    private String type;
    private String message; 
    private double price;
    private String image;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "coupons")
    private List<Customer> customers;
```

[image]

I have customers:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int cust_id;

    @Size(min=1,message="is required")
    private String cust_name;

    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    private String password;
     @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinTable(
            name = "customer_coupon", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cust_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "coup_id") }
        )
    private List<Coupon> coupons;
```

[image]

and I have the connecting table customer_coupon:

[image]

This is the error I am getting when starting the project:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [coupons] contains physical column name [coup_id] referred to by multiple physical column names: [coupId], [coup_id]
```

I have no idea where it comes from, would love if someone could help me !

Comment: try rename  private long coup_id; to  private long coupId;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem...sorry.

Had another class `Company` that was referring to `coupId` as well:

```
     @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
        )
 @JoinColumn(name = "coupId")
private List<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList();
```

This is from the `Company` class.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Please explain how this can be considered as an answer and how it solves the problem

Comment: it was a long time ago but I believe that I had two Company classes reffering to the same coupId.

Answer (score 16):

To remove ambiguity use the `@Column` annotation:

```
@Column(name = "coup_id")
private long coupId;
```

This way you can name your Java attributes as you like and don't let JPA alone for interpreting them.

Comment: where did you get this private long coupId from? original is private long coup_id

Comment: tried it, still the same, I had @Column on everything before this post, had error with it & error without it

Comment: @RomanSterlin Maybe you should read deeper the OP's problem before downvoting an answer...
From the exception: `referred to by multiple physical column names: [coupId], ... `.
I don't think he has named a database column in camelCase, so in some part of the code, he defined the Coupon Id variable as `coupId`.

Comment: sorry your'e right, edit ur answer alil so I can remove downvote.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.

`@Column(name = "coup_id") private long coupId;`

and column in db table called `coup_id`.

I removed `@Column` annotation, and workin! Thats all.

Hibernate convert xX to x_x itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another situation where I had this problem is due to case sensitivity. I mentioned a column name as ownerid and ownerId in two classes. As per Error: Table [] contains logical column name [ownerid] referring to multiple physical column names [ownerid] and [owner_id]. I ended up spending a lot of time searching for owner_id.

Answer (score 0):

I have join table, that is also entity and have ManyToOne relationships to two tables, so it is not exactly this issue, but could help someone.

Adding `@MapsId(`property name`)` to `@ManyToOne` property worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because of miss the mapped by
i was have the issue in this code

```
@OneToMany
@JsonManagedReference
private List<TweetsEntity> userTweets;
```

---

but after make it this way (add the mappedBy)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<TweetsEntity> userTweets;
```

its solved for me